# Yii Framework 2.0 Duplicate key value for primary key

Tags: php, postgresql, yii2

I am not understanding how its showing the duplicate value error for primary key even though id is an auto increment and primary key.See my error below.

```
Integrity constraint violation – yii\db\IntegrityException

SQLSTATE[23505]: Unique violation: 7 ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "user_pkey"
DETAIL: Key (id)=(2) already exists.
```

Comment: it means smth inserted a row without using sequence or updated id to value 2

Comment: ya correct..how its taking 2 also making me confusion?

Comment: i have done the application in localhost and pushed it into the heroku..After that only its showing error..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it means smth inserted a row without using sequence or updated id to value 2

**example:**

```
t=# create table so47(id serial primary key,v text);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into so47(v) select 'some';
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into so47(id,v) select 2, 'more';
INSERT 0 1
t=# insert into so47(v) select 'some more';
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "so47_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(2) already exists.
```

**answering the question in comment:**
postgres uses sequences to get next value for autoincrement column. To check the next value, run (in my example case):

```
t=# select * from so47_id_seq ;
 sequence_name | last_value | start_value | increment_by |      max_value      | min_value | cache_value | log_cnt | is_cycled | is_called
---------------+------------+-------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+---------+-----------+-----------
 so47_id_seq   |          2 |           1 |            1 | 9223372036854775807 |         1 |           1 |      31 | f         | t
(1 row)
```

**to reset nextval, you have to:**

```
t=# alter sequence so47_id_seq restart with 3;
ALTER SEQUENCE
t=# insert into so47(v) select 'some more';
INSERT 0 1
```

Then it will resume sequence from not existing value.

In your case you need:

```
select max(id)+1 from "user"
```

to get the value and then:

```
alter sequence user_id_seq restart with SELECTED_VALUE;
```